# Error when installing helm chart using terraform helm provider `User "client" cannot create deployments.extensions in the namespace "kube-system"`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install helm using the `Helm Provider` using the following terraform script

```
data "google_client_config" "current" {}

provider "helm" {
  tiller_image = "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:${var.helm_version}"
  max_history  = 250

  kubernetes {
    host                   = "${google_container_cluster.eu.endpoint}"
    token                  = "${data.google_client_config.current.access_token}"
    client_certificate     = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.eu.master_auth.0.client_certificate)}"
    client_key             = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.eu.master_auth.0.client_key)}"
    cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.eu.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "mydatabase" {
  name  = "mydatabase"
  chart = "stable/mariadb"

  set {
    name  = "mariadbUser"
    value = "foo"
  }

  set {
    name  = "mariadbPassword"
    value = "qux"
  }
}
```

but I'm geting the following error

```
* helm_release.mydatabase: 1 error(s) occurred:

* helm_release.mydatabase: error installing: deployments.extensions is forbidden: User "client" cannot create deployments.extensions in the namespace "kube-system"
```

I think this is happening when terraform helm provider attempts to install tiller can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you are on the right way, but.. here I agree with @hk'.

> helm_release.mydatabase: error installing: deployments.extensions is
>   forbidden: User "client" cannot create deployments.extensions in the
>   namespace "kube-system

The above error only belongs to authorization.
Lots of people meet difficulties during the installation and configuration of Helm provider. For example [github open issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/issues/148). There are couple of ideas there that may help you.

What may work for you is described in this article: [helm provider is Pain](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/ati5a8/helm_provider_is_pain/).
There is a solution in it that works for people.

Try next:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "tiller" {
  metadata {
    name      = "tiller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  automount_service_account_token = true
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "tiller" {
  metadata {
    name = "tiller"
  }

  role_ref {
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "cluster-admin"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }

  subject {
    kind = "ServiceAccount"
    name = "tiller"

    api_group = ""
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}

provider "helm" {
  version = "~> 0.7"

  debug           = true
  install_tiller  = true
  service_account = "${kubernetes_service_account.tiller.metadata.0.name}"
  namespace       = "${kubernetes_service_account.tiller.metadata.0.namespace}"
  tiller_image    = "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.11.0"

  kubernetes {
    config_path = "~/.kube/${var.env}"
  }
}
```

or

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "tiller" {
  metadata {
    name = "tiller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "tiller" {
  metadata {
        name = "tiller"
  }
  subject {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "User"
    name      = "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:tiller"
  }

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind  = "ClusterRole"
    name = "cluster-admin"
  }
  depends_on = ["kubernetes_service_account.tiller"]
}

provider "helm" {
    tiller_image = "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.12.3"
    install_tiller = true
    service_account = "tiller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's role and authorization related issue. reset helm using "helm reset" then run below command to resolve your issue.

curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get > get_helm.sh

chmod 700 get_helm.sh

./get_helm.sh

kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller

kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

helm init

kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'

Comment: I am attempting to install tiller through a terraform script so would want/need this to happen using terraform or report a bug in the helm provider

Comment: I think your script not install helm tiller but it's install mariadb using helm through script

Comment: @hk' it does install tiller, `helm init` installs tiller, but author asked to install tiller through terraform helm provider only